# Error using include and with in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, tags

I have a problem using tags in django templates. Here is part of my code in HTML file:

```
{% for habitacion in habitaciones %}
    {% with template_name=habitacion.url|add:".html" habitación_name=habitacion.name %}
        {% include "pacientes/habitaciones/"|add:template_name with habitacionNum=""|add:habitacion_name %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:6 %}<hr>{% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is my views.py code:

```
def AdministrativoView( request ):
    pacientes = Pacientes.objects.all()
    habitaciones = [{'url':'habitacionAdmLlena', 'name':'Habitación 1'},{'url':'habitacionAdmLlena', 'name':'Habitación 2'},{'url':'habitacionAdmVacia', 'name':'Habitación 3'},
    template_name = "pacientes/pacientes_administrativo.html"
    return render_to_response( template_name, { 'pacientes': pacientes, 'habitaciones': habitaciones } )
```

I want create dynamically the content of include tag, is posible to do this? I know that my code have many errors, or one at least, but I can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible what you want to do. From what I see your view has an error in defining the `habitaciones` variable. You missed a square bracket at the end: `]`

Comment: Can you also tell us what error your code is giving?

Comment: Thanks, but this bracket is only and error in copy/paste. Django don't give me any error, but don't show anything for the second variable.

Comment: I can show the value from the first context variable (from with) (template_name), but I can't show the value from the second context variable (form with) (habitacion_name). Thanks!

Comment: I see in your code that the names differ: `habitación_name` and `habitacion_name`

Comment: Yes, that's because I'm spanish and my browser corrects my "spelling errors".

Comment: Well you must provide the exact code. How can we know what you meant to post?

Comment: Oh sorry, I would get this code dynamically: {% include "paciente/habitaciones/template_name with habitacionNum=habitacion_name %} where template_name is a name of HTML file and habitacion_name is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Place I would do the logic in the view, generate an array of relative URLs (what you now do in the template) and then just iterate the list in the template and include each in turn.

That way your template code gets cleaner. Additionally debugging code in a view is much easier than template code, because template tags lacks good Error Codes.

Trying to Use the least possible amount of template tags is a good idea. The add filter seems to me the Bad boy, which is exactly what I d do in the view.

You could also generate an array of dicts, if you need more variables to be attached to your include statements.

Hope his helps - que te vaya bien.

Comment: Thanks, I do this and it Works well. I generate an array of "Habitaciones" and I compare it to obtain URL.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem before, I want to `include` different `base.html` according the views function in one html template. Unfortunately, I failed... and I try another way.

1. `{% include base.html %}` in every template html
2. make some change to the base.html

   ```
   {% if case1 %}
       ...
   {% elif case2 %}
       ...
   {% endif %}
   ```

I know it is a rough way, but can work

Comment: Really thanks! This works, but is a rough way and I want to find another solution. Thanks anyway!